# How to combined ajax div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is my Ajax script... I want to combined the first and the second ...

1st

```
  <script>
    function Ajax()
    {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        setTimeout('Ajax()',3000);
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","Home.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }

    window.onload=function(){
         setTimeout('Ajax()',3000);
       }
    </script>
```

2nd

```
<script>
    function Ajax()
    {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("myDiv2").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        setTimeout('Ajax()',3000);
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","Home2.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }

    window.onload=function(){
         setTimeout('Ajax()',3000);
       }
    </script>
```

---

```
<body>

<div id="myDiv"></div>
<div id="myDiv2"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: both are same why you want to combine them? just call the function twice

Comment: @Robin I tried... but doesn't work... :(

Comment: LOL why you declare a function twice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `setInterval` to refresh them every 3 seconds. function `Ajax` should be declared only once.

```
//Create a function to pass URL to call
//and  a function which will execute on sucess
function Ajax(url, callback) {
    var xmlhttp;
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            callback(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
window.onload = function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        //Call first url and set response text of div 1
        Ajax("Home.php", function(responseText) {
            document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = responseText;
        })
        //Call other url and set response text of div 2
        Ajax("Home2.php", function(responseText) {
            document.getElementById("myDiv2").innerHTML = responseText;
        })
    }, 3000);
}
```

---

As [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) is tagged, this can be used

```
$(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $('#myDiv').load('Home.php');
        $('#myDiv2').load('Home2.php');
    }, 3000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to use jQuery (since you tagged your question with it), this would be your answer:

```
function jQueryGet1(){
    $.get('Home.php', function(data){
        $('#myDiv').html(data);
        setTimeout(jQueryGet1, 3000);
    });
}
function jQueryGet2(){
    $.get('Home2.php', function(data){
        $('#myDiv2').html(data);
        setTimeout(jQueryGet2, 3000);
    });
}
$(window).load(function(){
    setTimeout(jQueryGet1, 3000);
    setTimeout(jQueryGet2, 3000);
});
```

**Note:** Since your Ajax calls are to 2 different locations, you can not combine these two functions. Each must be implemented separately.

Comment: How to add the setTimeout in this method?

Comment: When exactly do you need for these calls to be made? Do you need to make them after the page content is loaded?

Comment: So calling setTimeout after every call is completed is the optimum way of making sure the calls don't get mixed up if one iteration takes longer to finish. Check the updated code.

Comment: It should be `setTimeout(jQueryGet1, 3000);`, function name without quotes since you are passing the function reference.

Comment: @Satpal yes you are right. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @Satpal it's ok pal. Don't know why anyone would though!